Two different approaches for calculating enthalpy change for methane + HCl
I know that $\Delta{H}=H_{products}-H_{reactants}$ and also we can use $\Delta{H}=\Sigma{H}_{bonds broken}-\Sigma{H}_{bonds formed}$.
Take the example of methane + HCl.  If you calculate the total bonds broken enthalpy (I know not every bond breaks but this is how I was taught) you get 2087 kJ/mol.  If you calculate the total bonds formed enthalpy you get 1997 kJ/mol.  So, using $\Delta{H}=\Sigma{H}_{bonds broken}-\Sigma{H}_{bonds formed}$ we have $\Delta{H}=90$ kJ/mol.  But if you use the other formula you then get -90 kJ/mol.
I know that the reaction is exothermic so -90 kJ/mol is right.  However, I am not sure how to use the bonds broken-bonds formed approach.
$CH_4+HCl->CH_3Cl+H_2$

How did you get a negative value (-90k/mol) using the products - reactants formula? Standard formation enthalpies for $\ce{CH4}$, $\ce{HCl}$, and $\ce{CH3Cl}$ are -74.87, -92.31, and -83.68, respectively.
$$\Delta H°=-83.68-(-92.31-74.87)kJ/mol = 83.5 kJ/mol$$

You should replace $H$ by $\Delta H$, in both equations, for the first one with $\Delta_\text{f} H$, f as formation.

If you are searching for errors or mistakes, you have to write all steps. As others cannot point out a faulty step if it is not there.

The first formula is only used to calculate the difference in energies of the reactants and products, so for this you have your endothermic and exothermic graphs to determine $\Delta{H}$. The second formula is used for bond enthalpies. Bond enthalpies are different from reactants/products enthalpy. For example, the C-H bond has an average bond enthalpy of 413 kJ/mol.

So in this example using the bond enthalpies cannot tell me if its exothermic or endothermic?

@b20 They can, but just don't combine the 2 formulas, if you are calculating the bond enthalpies, use the bond enthalpy formula (with bonds broken and bonds formed). If you are given energy values of the reactants or products, then use the H_products-H_reactants

To use H_products - H_reactants would it be most correct to look for standard enthalpies of formation for each reactant and product?

@b20 Combining bond energies and enthalpies (reaction, formation, bond breaking, bond forming) is extremely demanding on attention regarding proper signs and sign conventions.  If you get the result sign flipped, you have made such an error in high probability.
